# google map is not displaying with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

```js
var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 16,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.511325, 73.820176),
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });

        var iconBase = 'img/contactus/';
        var icons = {
          info: {
            icon: iconBase + 'map.png'
          }
        };

        var features = [
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(18.511325, 73.820176),
            type: 'info'
          }
        ];

        // Create markers.
        features.forEach(function(feature) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: feature.position,
            icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
            map: map
          });
        });
      }
```

```css
 #map{
    margin-left: 20%; 
    height:100;
  }
```

```html
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA9rik1af5EY8G-fO6KNukN0-ROACLhAPg&callback=initMap">
    </script>

<div id="map" class="map" style="width: 65%; height:40%"></div>
```

hello above code is for Google map, i am integrating Google map inside my project & display custom logo in it. but its not displaying map to me i am using bootstrap.but when click on inspect element & uncheck position:relative then my map is displaying but not in proper way it should look like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps not showing up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419280/google-maps-not-showing-up)

Comment: Link for fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4a87k/846/ and you can see my answer below on what I have changed to make it work

Comment: `height:100;` that's the problem, there's no fall back for that unit-less in html5.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle, modified your css and it seems working. The only issue was css. The map is getting hidden after loading. here is the CSS:

```
 #map{
  position:fixed !important;
  display:block !important;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i hope it will works , just do in the below way, remove all inline css and 
add a height: 500px;  
<style>
  #map{
       margin-left: 20%; 
       height:500px;
      }
 </style>
 <script>
   var map;
   function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 16,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(18.511325, 73.820176),
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });

    var iconBase = 'img/contactus/';
    var icons = {
      info: {
        icon: iconBase + 'map.png'
      }
    };

    var features = [
      {
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(18.511325, 73.820176),
        type: 'info'
      }
    ];

    // Create markers.
    features.forEach(function(feature) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: feature.position,
        icon: icons[feature.type].icon,
        map: map
      });
    });
  }
 </script>
  <script async defer
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyA9rik1af5EY8G-
  fO6KNukN0-ROACLhAPg&callback=initMap">
  </script>

  <div id="map" class="map"></div>
```